# function not return value php

Tags: php, function, recursion

The following function does not return any value when if statement is true; otherwise it is returning `$var1`; it shows the correct value.

```
function setValue($var1) {
    global $con;
    global $k;
    $k++;
    $var1 = strtolower($var1);
    $var1 = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/', '-', $var1);
    $var1 = preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $var1);
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con, "select * from tbl_name where name='".$var1."'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) {            
        setValue($var1.'-'.$k);
    }
    else {
        //die($var1);
        return $var1;
    }           
}
```

Comment: It is not returning because no return statement present for `true` condition.

Comment: did you *print_r* it like this *print_r(setValue());* ?

Comment: for `true` condition its a recursive cal, still i need to add return?

Comment: Can't do that. recursivecall+return at the same time

Comment: @Mittul `print_r(setValue());` where should i put it?  'm getting correct value when i die inside else,but it is not returning

Comment: have a return in `true` condition.

Comment: @Asif you can put this anywhere where you able to call this function.

Comment: still nothing print

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry i didn't see it's recursive but seems like you are doing it wrong still. return and recursive like that is not a good idea. I think you should return values by this method and then use it in a loop by passing var and k parameters.

First of all you need to check your if statement. You are not returning any value if first condition is true, you are calling some method only.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result1)>0)
{           
    setValue($var1.'-'.$k);
    return($var1);
}
else
{
    "Give some error to user here";
     return($var1); //if you still want to see it...
}
```

It's better to inform user if "else" is true while you are checking DB works like that.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
setValue($var1.'-'.$k);
```

to:

```
return ($var1.'-'.$k);
```